# SQL calculated column based on other calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a list of invoices, In one query I calculate the invoice due date based on the terms of the invoice (7days/30 days etc)

I have following layout:

InvoiceNr | InvoiceDate | InvoiceDueDate

I want to add now an extra column to put the invoice in an ageing bucket based on the current date. for example:

InvoiceNr | InvoiceDate | InvoiceDueDate | ageing

But it seems that I cannot create that extra column based on the InvoiceDueDate column because thats already a combined column. So question how can I create a query which can and calculate the duedate, and calculate the ageing of that invoice.

The base invoice table looks likes this:

```
Customer    Name    InvoiceTerms Description        Invoice        InvoiceDate  Value   InvoiceBal1
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050033 2015-11-06  0.00    0.00
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050034 2015-11-06  550.00  0.00
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050037 2015-11-09  362.18  0.00
```

With following query, I add the invoice due dates

```
    SELECT     dbo.ArInvoice.Customer, dbo.ArCustomer.Name, dbo.ArCustomer.CustomerOnHold, dbo.ArCustomer.CreditStatus, dbo.ArCustomer.TermsCode AS CustomerTerms, 
                      dbo.ArInvoice.TermsCode AS InvoiceTerms, dbo.TblArTerms.Description, dbo.ArInvoice.Invoice, CAST(dbo.ArInvoice.InvoiceDate AS date) AS InvoiceDate, 
                      CAST(CASE ArInvoice.TermsCode WHEN '00' THEN CAST(dbo.ArInvoice.InvoiceDate AS date) WHEN '22' THEN dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateAdd(month, MONTH(InvoiceDate), DateAdd(Year,
                       YEAR(InvoiceDate) - 1900, 0) + 1)), 0) - 1 WHEN '24' THEN dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateAdd(month, MONTH(InvoiceDate) + 1, DateAdd(Year, YEAR(InvoiceDate) - 1900, 0) + 1)), 0) 
                      - 1 WHEN '28' THEN dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateAdd(month, MONTH(InvoiceDate) + 2, DateAdd(Year, YEAR(InvoiceDate) - 1900, 0) + 1)), 0) 
                      - 1 ELSE InvoiceDate + TblArTerms.DueDays + TblArTerms.InvDayOfMonth END AS date) AS InvoiceDueDate, dbo.ArInvoice.CurrencyValue, dbo.ArInvoice.InvoiceBal1
FROM         dbo.ArCustomer INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ArInvoice ON dbo.ArCustomer.Customer = dbo.ArInvoice.Customer INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TblArTerms ON dbo.ArInvoice.TermsCode = dbo.TblArTerms.TermsCode
```

Which gives me

```
Customer    Name    InvoiceTerms Description        Invoice        InvoiceDate DueDate    Value   InvoiceBal1
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050033 2015-11-06  2015-11-06  0.00    0.00
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050034 2015-11-06  2015-11-06  550.00  0.00
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050037 2015-11-09  2015-11-09  362.18  0.00
```

So what I now need is an extra column which takes the invoiceDueDate,
checks if the difference between getdate() and the invoice days is bigger then 30 then it should say overdue.

For example:

```
Customer    Name    InvoiceTerms Description        Invoice        InvoiceDate DueDate    Value   InvoiceBal1   Ageing
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050033 2015-11-06  2015-11-06  0.00    0.00      OVERDUE
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050034 2015-11-06  2015-11-06  550.00  0.00      OVERDUE
    0000    CASH A/C        00  CASH ONLY ACCOUNT   000000000050037 2015-11-09  2015-11-09  362.18  0.00      OVERDUE
```

Currently the only way I can find is creating two views.
First one with the invoiceduedate and then a second one with the ageing.
but that feels a bit overkill? So trying to find a way to do it all in one query?

Comment: Use a CTE or subquery instead of a view.  You can even use `outer apply` if you want.  There is no reason to put the logic into views.

Comment: would you have a quick example for that? APPLY seems not so easy to use? Thanks a lot